# File replace in upload in php

Tags: php, file, upload, replace

I would like to delete a file that is already exists and add the new one in the same folder. 
I have taken the tmp name added it in a session. Deleted the existing already but it not movin in the new one.

```
<?php
session_start();
$files = $_SESSION['Already'];
$tmp=$_SESSION['PATH'];
unlink('../upload/'.$files);
$to="../upload/".$files; 
move_uploaded_file($tmp,$to);
?>
```

Comment: What do those `$files` and `$temp` have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the files. If the files name are exactly same, you don't need to unlink them. Just using `move_uploaded_file()` will do.

Its important to know what is causing the error. Check your server `error_logs` for such informations.

Comment: I have checked it and it deletes the contents

Comment: @Mervyn, Checked what? and deletes what?